# Managed C++, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c++-cli, managed, nullreferenceexception, runtime-error

I've run into this problem before, but never in a situation like this. I'm completely confused. As the question states, I'm getting the runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Using the debugger tools, I think I've pinpointed the problem to this line:

```cpp
dataFileLocation = path;
```

The entire function is here:

```cpp
void DATReader::SetPath(String^ path) 
{
    if(!File::Exists(path))
    {
        MessageBox::Show( "DATReader (missing dat file: \n"+path+"\n )", "Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation);
        return;
    }
    dataFileLocation = path;
}
```

`dataFileLocation` is declared here, but nothing is assigned to it:

```cpp
ref class DATReader
{
private:
    System::String^ dataFileLocation;
    // ...
}
```

Now I know the reason I'm getting the error is because `dataFileLocation` is assigned to nothing. But I'm having problems assigning it. When I add `= 0;` to it, it won't build because its a ref class. When I try to assigned it to `= 0;` in the constructor, it yells at me for trying to convert it from a `System::String^` to an `int`. If I assign it to a `= gcnew String("");` it builds, but throws the same runtime exception.

I don't get it, am I reading the debugger wrong, and this isn't the source of the problem at all? I've just started to use managed code recently, so I'm confused :\

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `path` that's null?

Comment: path being null shouldn't cause that error on that line - granted, if the error is on a different line, that could be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed C++ uses `nullptr` for null references.  So you can check:

```
if (path == nullptr) { ... }
```

or use:

```
if (!String::IsNullOrEmpty(path))
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the nullptr keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check and make sure your DATReader object isn't null as well It may be throwing the exception at your DATReader.SetPath() call.

Comment: I can approve this, I had such an error right now. While debugging it seemed that DATReader object would have been created and I could step into its method, just to fail on the first line. But there was nothing wrong with the parameter I gave, it just was the DATReader reference beeing null...

Answer (score 2):

This is a nicety in C# that's missing in C++/CLI.  C# generates code that ensures *this* can never be null.  Easily seen in the debugger by setting a breakpoint on the method and inspecting "this".  Here's an example program that reproduces the exception:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class Example {
    String^ dataFileLocation;
public:
    void SetPath(String^ path) { 
        dataFileLocation = path;   // Set breakpoint here and inspect "this"
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Example^ obj /* = gcnew Example */;
    obj->SetPath("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

Remove the /* */ comments to fix.  Fix your code by looking at the call stack to find the method that forgot to instantiate the object.